# Is the "conjugate" of irrational numbers standard terminology?

Tags: irrational-numbers

In some high school text books I find theorems called "Irrational Conjugate Theorem" (or similar) related to irrational roots of rational polynomials. More precisely they call the number $p-\sqrt{q}$ the "conjugate" of $p+\sqrt{q}$ ($p$, $q$ rationals, $\sqrt{q}$ not rational). The statements themselves are (more or less) correct, but I find it strange to use the phrase "conjugate" in this context.

I searched on the web and I did not find any resources above high school level that uses this term. I also searched on this forum and when a question asks about irrational conjugates (there are quite a few) the answers and comments mostly start along the lines "what do you mean by conjugate?"

My question is the following. Is there a universally accepted definition of a conjugate of irrational numbers (or certain type of irrational numbers)? If yes, I would appreciate a reference to a proper resource (not a high school text or a website helping high school students with their homework).

Comment: It is a special case of  [Galois conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_element_(field_theory)) from field extension theory, when the minimal polynomial is of degree two. The conjugate is the other root of the minimal polynomial with rational coefficients that $p-\sqrt{q}$ is a root of. Complex conjugate is another special case encountered in elementary contexts.

Comment: See e.g. [Swallow, Exploratory Galois Theory, p. 105](https://books.google.com/books/about/Exploratory_Galois_Theory.html?id=7rFboVfCR_0C).